# is it possible to make an iphone app that will only call to one number?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to make an iphone app that will only call to one number no matter what number was dialed?

Answer (score 2):

you could write an app that has some number you have hard coded into it.  When the user initiates some function you have programmed, your application will hand off the request to actual phone application with the number you specify.

If you are asking whether you can override the built in nature of the phone to circumvent the original dialer such that only one number is able to be called, I dont believe this is possible.  YOu have no control over native applications.

Comment: if the phone were to be jailbroken do you see a possibility?

Comment: Hmmm I can't say as I'm really not sure what is possible with a jailbroken iPHone in terms of development. If its more the solution you are interested in rather than the platform, I can say with some certainty that this type of app would be much more do-able on Android

Comment: I think you can do pretty much anything on a jailbroken iPhone, although you’ll probably have to do some reverse-engineering.

I can’t quite imagine a universe where this app is at all useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about whether you could override the telephone function so that it would dial call your number, no matter what the user dialed, that would be a horrible security violation.  You could prevent emergency calls or make the phone dial some high-cost 1-900 number.  Of course Apple won't let you do this.  Even if you could do this on a jailbroken phone, I could see it being abused by the wrong parties.

If all you are asking is how to dial a particular phone number from within your application, you can simply use the URL scheme like the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-555-555-5555"]];
```

Comment: Don't think this is what he was asking for but it was what I was looking for! +1